# Linq Query with dynamic type

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, dataset, typing

I am using the following linq to parse a dataset that I have returned:

```
 row.Field<long?>("id").HasValue == false &&
```

The problem I'm running into is that when the dataset is obtained from Sql Server, the field needs to be parsed with `<int?>` and when it's obtained from Oracle, it needs to be parsed as `<long?>`.  Is there a way to create a variable that I can pass in to the .Field method to dynamically set this data type?  I'd like to have something like this:

```
Type T = IsSqlServer ? typeof(int?) : typeof(long?);
....
row.Field<T>("id").HasValue == false &&
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you use the `dynamic` keyword?

Comment: @Killercam That worked!  If you make it an answer, I'll mark it when I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dynamic` keyword for just this purpose. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) for the programming guide.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could either use reflection (not recommended) or just use the ternary operator:

```
!(IsSqlServer ? row.Field<int?>("id").HasValue : row.Field<long?>("id").HasValue)
```

Comment: I was looking for a cleaner solution than this.  I have probably 100 usages of this in the code that I'm working on and it's going to make it much less readable.

Comment: @mrK You could pack it into a method then. I could show you the reflection, but it would be ugly as.

Comment: Actually, @Killercam had a suggestion in the comments that worked great.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @mrK Huh. I honestly wasn't expecting dynamic. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension method:

```
public static class DataRowHelpers
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> FieldSpecialized = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();

    public static bool FieldHasValue(this DataRow row, Type type, string column)
    {
        MethodInfo fieldSpecialized;

        if(!FieldSpecialized.TryGetValue(type, out fieldSpecialized))
        {       
            var extensions = typeof(DataRowExtensions);
            var fieldGeneric = extensions.GetMethod("Field",
                                                    new[] { typeof(DataRow), typeof(string) });
            fieldSpecialized = fieldGeneric.MakeGenericMethod(type);

            FieldSpecialized.Add(type, fieldSpecialized);
        }


        return fieldSpecialized.Invoke(null, new object[] { row, column }) != null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var type = IsSqlServer ? typeof(int?) : typeof(long?);

var predicate = row.FieldHasValue(type, "id");
```